# create string-format using re.compile() and extend to check length

Tags: python, compilation, variable-length

I need to check format and length of an email in ONE command.
dont want to use

```
if len(.... ) == ...:
```

used re.compile(some conditions)

```
EMAIL_FORMAT = re.compile(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+")
```

I want to extend this to also check the length --> need to keep in 1 command if possible

```
if re.match(EMAIL_FORMAT, _email_variable):
         print("length and format ok")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a non-consuming capture, and add an expression that matches exact length,

try this:

`EMAIL_FORMAT = re.compile(r"(?=[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+)(?=.{10})")`

(change `{10}` to whatever length you need, you can also use a range like `{5,25}`)

**NOTE:** to be honset, using `... and length ==` is much more readable